# Subfigures at bottom of a float bunch together

Tags: spacing, graphics, floats

So I have 39 `.pdf` standalone graphics which I am putting into a wider document by making a figure on each page, every one of which has up to twelve graphics in it, three to a line, as subfigures. An image is below.[image: cubes]

However, as you can see, the last cubes on a line seem to sort of bunch together, even though the code for them is the same as that of the others. This is despite lots of space in every direction.

Edit: Here is a working example which shows the bunching on the bottom row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{f-1.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{f-2.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{f-3.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{f-4.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{f-5.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{f-6.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{f-7.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{f-8.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{f-9.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{f-10.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{f-11.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{f-12.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Without seeing a MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small complete document), which reproduce your problem is very difficult to help you. In normal circumstance, if all rows of images have equal spaces between images, this should not happen. Sub image placement option (`t` or `b`) hasn't influence on horizontal position of images. Also instead of `\includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{...}` try to use `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{...}`.

Comment: Working example added. I could have stripped it down a little but I hope it is OK as is. I tried switching ```[height=3.5cm]{...}``` for ```[width=\linewidth]{...}``` but it did not work, bunching is still there.

Comment: I'm not sure how useful the example is currently, because obviously it depends on 12 other files in the same directory which I can't really attach, but even if I recreate it with ```usepackage[demo]{graphicx}``` and then ```image1``` etc., there is still the same problem.

Comment: Your problem has source in images' sizes and from missing empty lines between rows with images (after each third image). For details see my answer below.

Comment: Yes, changed to fit your format with ```\medskip``` and ```\hfil``` and now it works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Lets assume, that all images have the same size and the same (white) borders  (generated by the `standalone` document class with the same options, for example `\documentclass[tikz, border=0pt]{standalone}`
- Determining the height of the images alone does not guarantee that the images will be positioned horizontally as desired. It can happens, that they will spill-out of `subfigure` environments.
- Instead defining the heights of images only is better to define their widths. With this is assured, that all images has the same width and can be easily evenly distributed in figure's rows. IN this case the heights of images will be adopted to their widths so, that images' aspect ratios will be preserved.
- If for some reason you like to have images height 35mm, than regardless to eventual distortion of images aspect ratios, than you can prescribe heights and widths of images.
- Rows of images should be separated by empty lines. For distances between images 'rows you can after empty lines add some vertical skip, for example `\smallskip`.
- Since your real images are not available, in MWE are used demo images defined in the `graphicx` package (showed as black rectangles):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % in real document remove option `demo`
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth} % set widths for all images
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics{f-1.pdf}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics{f-2.pdf}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics{f-3.pdf}
\end{subfigure}

\smallskip
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics{f-4.pdf}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics{f-5.pdf}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics{f-6.pdf}
\end{subfigure}

\smallskip
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics{f-7.pdf}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics{f-8.pdf}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics{f-9.pdf}
\end{subfigure}

\smallskip
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics{f-10.pdf}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics{f-11.pdf}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics{f-12.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]